# Cloudfront and ELB problem with redirecting from http to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, http-redirect

I have simple stack: EC2, ELB, Route53 and Cloudfront.
I would like to enable CachingOptimized in Cache policy howewer I get error in Firefox:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

I have a few important configuration from Cloudfront:

```
Origin: main-albxxxxxx-amazonaws.com 
Protocol: HTTPS only
```

Behaviors

```
Origin and origin groups: main-albxxxxxx-amazonaws.com
Viewer protocol policy: Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
Cache policy:CachingOptimized
Origin request policy - optional: AllViewer
```

Listeners in ELB:

```
HTTPS:443
Forward to
prod-tg-1 : 1 (100%)
Group-level stickiness: Off

HTTP:80
If (all match)
Request is not otherwise routed
Then
Redirect to HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}
Status code: HTTP_301
```

Route53:
Alias to CloudFront distribution

I would like to redirect site from www. and http to https.

On https://www.redirect-checker.orgI  I get error:
Too many redirects. Please try to reduce your number of redirects. Actually you use 19 Redirects. Ideally you should not use more than 3 Redirects in a redirect chain. More than 3 redirections will produce unnecessary load on your server and reduces speed, which ends up in bad user experience.
Distribution IDs or URLs:
CloudFront Request IDs(X-Amz-Cf-Id):
Error Message:

curl -v
CACHE DISABLED

```
* Connected to example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.example.com
*  start date: Feb 21 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  3 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55815ae6fe90)
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< date: Fri, 03 Mar 2023 20:13:17 GMT
< cache-control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
< content-language: en
< expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
< permissions-policy: interest-cohort=()
< server: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-generator: Drupal 9 (https://www.drupal.org)
< x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
< x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 740769d10d5ef217a54d33b1ec64faf4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: FRA56-P3
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
< x-amz-cf-id: pMRmxUYZ12XIdG0aca3JOxGPTJmCO61FCwDc0776RtgVHOtfdP-hxA==

< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
  </body>
</html>
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

CACHE OPTIMIZED

```
  ~ curl -v https://example.com
*   Trying 108.138.51.45:443...
* Connected to example.com (108.138.51.45) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.example.com
*  start date: Feb 21 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  3 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x5564f16c1e90)
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
< HTTP/2 301 
< content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< content-length: 312
< location: http://example.com/
< date: Sun, 26 Feb 2023 21:04:13 GMT
< cache-control: max-age=1209600
< expires: Sun, 12 Mar 2023 21:04:13 GMT
< server: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 444c86780ce99d2fc729208a25cb6aa2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: WAW51-P2
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
< x-amz-cf-id: 2Yx7ai-qlcR8vG7GlWOnrVExnN4C4adxzDDcQ85vpn6JJZ8AYgypBA==
< age: 429589
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://example.com/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Server at www.example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

and error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: I think you shouldn't be listening on port 80 on ELB because CloudFront is redirecting all HTTP to HTTPS and it is the first layer on entry (well before ELB), please try removing HTTP:80 on the ELB.

Comment: Do you have your own custom domain? You can't use https for ELB's domain provided by aws.

Comment: Yes, I have own custom domain with certificate from Certificate Manager.

Comment: It would be interesting what is redirecting to what, can you do a "curl -v https://..." and post the logs?
Also not only CloudFront can redirect, the application behind can also do redirects...!

Comment: @Augunrik Logs above before and after enable cache on Cloudfront

Comment: @Sri I removed HTTP Listener from ELB and I also get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: From the information you have given the AWS setup looks ok (regarding redirection); my guess would be that the application behind the ELB is doing the redirects. Can you validate to which domains it redirects or tries to redirect with the many tries?

Comment: @Augunrik I have this redirection in the app:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Could they be duplicated? But why only after enabling cache on Cloudfront?